# Override components , like services?

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

Say we import one of Angular Material modules :

```
 providers:[],
 imports : [MaterialInput]
```

Inside `MaterialInput` , there is a component used named : MaterialInputComponent

For some reasons I want to override that component with my own

So I want to be able to say :

```
 providers:[
    {
       provide: MaterialInputComponent,
       useClass : MyOwnInputComponent
    }
 ],
 imports : [MaterialInputModule]
```

I know we can override services like that, but can it be done for components or directives as well ?

***UPDATE*** : 
I am not looking for Component inheritance, what I want is to use something like `Material Module` but sometimes I want to override some it's components behaviours, like you do with services.

Like :

If this is the original code behind MaterialInput component , which is in my node module.

```
  @Component({})
  export class OriginalMaterialInputComonent{
        greet(){ alert('Say Aloo'); }
  }
```

And I have a similar class like :

```
  @Component({})
  export class OverrideMaterialInputComonent{

        greet(){ alert('Say yes we can'); } // overriden function
  }
```

And, say I'm importing the hole MaterialInputModule

```
declarations:[
   {
    provide: OriginalMaterialInputComonent,
    useClass : OverrideMaterialInputComonent
  }
],
  imports : [MaterialInputModule]
```

Is that doable?

Comment: Which version of Angular 2 are you using? Component inheritance is available with Angular 2.3

Answer (score -1):

You can use decorators for that, You can look into the below jsfiddle  example

```
Overriding components
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mohan_rathour/sqv0jx21/

Comment: Please post relevant code here, rather than a link that may go dead in the future

Comment: @peeskillet  That code is created by myself and will not dead in future

Comment: @mohanrathour is this AngularJS ? My question is in Angular2

Comment: it's angular 1.5.8, but you can also use decorators into angular 2 as well